# How to install SSL key and certificate on SG 300-10 (and SSH functionality)

Tags: cisco, ssh

How to install our own SSL key and certificate on a SG-300-10 switch?

The manual simply doesn't seem to bear much resemblance to what's available in the web interface.

According to the manual, one should navigate to "Security > SSL Server > SSL Server Authentication Settings".  But the only entries under Security are TACAS+, RADIUS, Password Strength, Management Access Authentication, Mgmt Access Method, TCP/UDP Services, Storm Control, Port Security, 802.1X, Denial of Service Prevention.

And, having looked through the other menus, I can't find anywhere else where this could be configured.

Similarly with SSH keys.  The manual talks about web interface pages called "SSH User Authentication" and "SSH Server Authentication", but the web interface I see does not have pages with these titles.  How would I go about reconfiguring, or even viewing, the SSH keys on the device?

Comment: What is the IOS release on your switcth? In order to support encryption, you need to make sure that you have the right IOS installed. Refer to [this](https://supportforums.cisco.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/3402835-103698/300%20series%20CLI%20firmware%201.1.pdf) link for the CLI commands. [This](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/iosswrel/ps1834/products_tech_note09186a00800fb9d9.shtml) link will help you understand the required IOS release for your requirements.

Comment: SG-300's are not FULL IOS devices, they are from the small business line and run an operating system that has slightly different syntax and drastically different functionality.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use an SG300 at home as my core switch. Getting SSH set up is not too bad:

```
conf t
crypto key generate rsa
ip ssh server
end
```

That will generate the SSH key and enable the SSH server. If you question-mark your way along those command structures you will find some options.

You can view the public and private RSA SSH keys with:

```
show crypto key rsa
```

I've not done an SSL cert import myself, but looking through the CLI I'd take a stab at the following:

```
conf t
crypto certificate 1 import
ip https certificate 1
```

There are two "slots" for certificates, so you can specify slot 1 or 2 for the import or a self-signed certificate generation.

The import function does not seem to have an option to install a PKCS12 certificate, so you may need to import the private key separately with:

```
conf t
crypto key import rsa
```

I'm not 100% sure on the SSL setup, but the SSH key setup above works.

Answer (score 0):

Related to what AdnanG said, check the firmware version on your switch. I have an SG300-28P, running version 1.3.7.18, and I see the "SSL Server | SSL Server Authentication Settings" section exactly where the manual says it should be.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your Display mode from Basic to Advanced

Comment: Welcome on this stack exchange site. Please consider adding some details to your answer to improve it, for example how your suggestion helps and how to actually do this.